# scalar subquery produced more than one element in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

When I try to execute below query, I get a error called "scalar subquery produced more than one element". Can anyone please help me understand where i went wrong?

looks like, the error is coming out in the select queries from where i am trying to fetch ID column. Can anyone help me understand technically? all the columns called in this query has string datatype.

```
SELECT A.ID,DATE,SKT3 FROM
(
SELECT SS.SK,DATE,
((SELECT 'CD_1' AS ID_1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE T1A IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'CD_2' AS ID_2 FROM TABLE1 WHERE T1B IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'CD_3' AS ID_3 FROM TABLE1 WHERE T1C IS NOT NULL)) AS ID
  FROM DB.TABLE1 T1
  JOIN DB.TABLE2 SS
  ON T1.SID = SS.SID) A
  JOIN DB.TABLE3 T3
  ON A.PID = T3.PID
```

Comment: Here a subquery is used.  This must be one single value, or you need to create an array with `array_agg( (( ... )) )`. I guess you want to do an inner Select. `Select * FROM ( Select * from tbl)` Please use CTE: `with tbl1 as (Select ...),tbl2 as (Select ..) Select * from tbl1 left join tbl2 ...`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a subquery. Please use the `CASE` statement.

```sql
WITH
  tblA AS (
  SELECT
    SS.SK,
    DATE,
    CASE
      WHEN id_1 IS NULL THEN "CD_1"
      WHEN id_2 IS NULL THEN "CD_2"
      WHEN id_3 IS NULL THEN "CD_3"
    ELSE
    "other"
  END
    AS ID
  FROM
    DB.TABLE1 T1
  JOIN
    DB.TABLE2 SS
  ON
    T1.SID = SS.SID)
SELECT
  A.ID,
  DATE,
  SKT3
FROM
  tblA
JOIN
  DB.TABLE3 T3
ON
  A.PID = T3.PID
```